Insert image with border in Plotly
To create a plotly scatter plot with images at each point, we can do:
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image

xs = [0, 1, 2]
ys = [0, 1, 4]
images = [Image.open("a.png"), Image.open("b.png"), Image.open("c.png")]

figure = px.scatter(x=xs, y=ys)

size = 2

for x, y, image in zip(xs, ys, images):
    figure.add_layout_image(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        source=Image.open(png),
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        sizex=size,
        sizey=size,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="middle",
    )

How to add a border around the image inserted without baking it into the image itself?
I suppose figure.add_shape could be used to add a rectangle as the border, something like:
figure.add_shape(
    type="rect",
    x0=x - size / 2,
    y0=y - size / 2,
    x1=x + size / 2,
    y1=y + size / 2,
    line=dict(
        color="red",
        width=2,
    ),
    opacity=0.5,
)

except that this draws the box in the wrong location.
I would like to use this question to document the correct parameters for positioning the box to be along the border of the image.

Hi Richie, if I'm not wrong, images is not defined.

@rpanai That's right, I left out images for my convenience in posting the question. Added placeholder now.

Because of the way the code is written, if both axes don't have the same scale, the box will draw incorrectly. This is because the coordinates in the graph that the image is drawn only respects one of the axis scales.
One solution is to make the axis scales equal, by adding:
figure.update_yaxes(
    scaleanchor="x",
    scaleratio=1,
)


Ensure that xref and yref are set to x and y respectively in figure.add_layout_image. This aligns the image with the scatter plot's axes.
The border will be positioned directly around the image. If you want a gap between the border and the image, you'll need to adjust the x0, y0, x1, and y1 values accordingly.
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image

xs = [0, 1, 2]
ys = [0, 1, 4]

figure = px.scatter(x=xs, y=ys)

size = 2

for x, y, image in zip(xs, ys, images):
    figure.add_layout_image(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        source=Image.open(png),
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        sizex=size,
        sizey=size,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="middle",
    )

    figure.add_shape(
        type="rect",
        x0=x - size / 2,
        y0=y - size / 2,
        x1=x + size / 2,
        y1=y + size / 2,
        line=dict(
            color="red",
            width=2,
        ),
        opacity=0.5,
    )

figure.show()


